# C# Sequential animation using Reactive Extensions (Rx)

Tags: animation, system.reactive, sequential

I try to use the RX to write a class to manager the animation sequence.unfortuntaly, I found that it does not work, when I debug it, I found that I always get the value of _sequence is null;It seems that No result is returned.I doubt that some wrong about the method AnimationSequence(). but I am not sure ,any expert can help me?

```
 public class AnimationManager : IDisposable
{
    private IDisposable _sequence;
    private ISequentialResult _result;

    private readonly List<Func<IObserver<ISequentialResult>, ISequentialResult, ISequentialResult>> _animationQueue
        = new List<Func<IObserver<ISequentialResult>, ISequentialResult, ISequentialResult>>();


    public void AddAnimation(Func<IObserver<ISequentialResult>, ISequentialResult, ISequentialResult> sequence)
    {
        _animationQueue.Add(sequence);
    }

    public void Run(Action<Exception> exception, Action<ISequentialResult> completed)
    {

        var sequence = AnimationSequence().ToObservable();

        _sequence = sequence.Subscribe(
            next => { },
            exception,
            () => completed(_result));
    }

    private IEnumerable<IObservable<Object>> AnimationSequence()
    {
        var x = 0;

        _result = new DefaultSeqResult(null) { Value = this };
        while (x < _animationQueue.Count)
        {
            var sequence = _animationQueue[x];


            var step = Observable.Create<ISequentialResult>(
                observer =>
                {
                    var newResult = sequence(observer, _result);
                    newResult.Results.Add(_result);
                    newResult.Results.AddRange(_result.Results);
                    _result = newResult;
                    return () => { };
                }
                );
            yield return step;

            x++;
        }

        _result.Results.Add(_result);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_sequence != null) _sequence.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. In `Run()` you are turning an `IEnumerable` into an `IObservable` only to immediately subscribe to it. This just looks to me like a needlessly roundabout way of immediately iterating over the `IEnumerable`, and a foreach loop is far more readable for that purpose.

You also ignore all the data from that `IEnumerable` (since your `OnNext`-handler is empty) and instead read the `_result` member variable that is somehow populated elsewhere, which makes it pointless to have that `IEnumerable` in the fist place.

Answer (score 0):

`_sequence` will not get a value until `Subscribe()` returns.  And since you are subscribing to an `IEnumerable.ToObservable()`, `Subscribe` ends up iterating over the enumerable completely before returning.  In effect, `Run` is going to block until the entire sequence is processed.

Secondly, what you are subscribing to is an `IObservable<IObservable<object>>`.  But you never iterate over the inner sequence and so they never actually do anything.  This is probably what you mean by "it does not work".

If you want to run the inner sequences sequentially, then do:

```
var sequence = AnimationSequence().Concat();
```

If you want to run the inner sequences in parallel, then do:

```
var sequence = AnimationSequence().Merge();
```

Either of those should make it "go".